how to keep threadPool object wait for all tasks finished?
The ThreadPool code is:
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "SafeQueue.h"

class ThreadPool {
private:
  class ThreadWorker {
  private:
    int m_id;
    ThreadPool * m_pool;
  public:
    ThreadWorker(ThreadPool * pool, const int id)
      : m_pool(pool), m_id(id) {
    }

    void operator()() {
      std::function<void()> func;
      bool dequeued;
      while (!m_pool->m_shutdown) {
        {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_pool->m_conditional_mutex);
          if (m_pool->m_queue.empty()) {
            m_pool->m_conditional_lock.wait(lock);
          }
          dequeued = m_pool->m_queue.dequeue(func);
        }
        if (dequeued) {
          func();
        }
      }
    }
  };

  bool m_shutdown;
  SafeQueue<std::function<void()>> m_queue;
  std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
  std::mutex m_conditional_mutex;
  std::condition_variable m_conditional_lock;
public:
  ThreadPool(const int n_threads)
    : m_threads(std::vector<std::thread>(n_threads)), m_shutdown(false) {
  }

  ThreadPool(const ThreadPool &) = delete;
  ThreadPool(ThreadPool &&) = delete;

  ThreadPool & operator=(const ThreadPool &) = delete;
  ThreadPool & operator=(ThreadPool &&) = delete;

  // Inits thread pool
  void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_threads.size(); ++i) {
      m_threads[i] = std::thread(ThreadWorker(this, i));
    }
  }

  // Waits until threads finish their current task and shutdowns the pool
  void shutdown() {
    m_shutdown = true;
    m_conditional_lock.notify_all();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m_threads.size(); ++i) {
      if(m_threads[i].joinable()) {
        m_threads[i].join();
      }
    }
  }

  // Submit a function to be executed asynchronously by the pool
  template<typename F, typename...Args>
  auto submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
    // Create a function with bounded parameters ready to execute
    std::function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Encapsulate it into a shared ptr in order to be able to copy construct / assign 
    auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);

    // Wrap packaged task into void function
    std::function<void()> wrapper_func = [task_ptr]() {
      (*task_ptr)(); 
    };

    // Enqueue generic wrapper function
    m_queue.enqueue(wrapper_func);

    // Wake up one thread if its waiting
    m_conditional_lock.notify_one();

    // Return future from promise
    return task_ptr->get_future();
  }
};

Test code here:
int add(const int x, const int y) {
  return x + y;
}

int main() {
  ThreadPool pool(2);

  pool.init();
  auto ret = pool.submit(add, 1, 3);
  auto result = ret.get();
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}

I found that when the tasks in the thread pool are completed, if I do not call the shutdown() method, the entire process will be blocked. I'm wondering without calling thread.join(), how does it ensure that the main thread doesn't get destroyed before the worker threads?
I use large models to help me parse the code. What it tells me is that the thread object holds a reference to the thread pool

Signaling all threads to exit and joining them is the proper thing to do. Otherwise nothing prevents them from keep running after the main thread exits.

your ThreadPool object has a vector<thread>, so when the threadpool is destroyed it will try to destroy them.
if a std::thread destructor is called before .join was called on it then it calls std::terminate which instantly exits your application, there is no waiting.
if you want the main thread to wait for workers to finish then you should call shutdown in the ThreadPool destructor
~ThreadPool()
{
  if (!m_shutdown)
    shutdown()
}


I understacn what you said,but the code I posted has achieved the effect you mentioned, and it does not call shutdown in the destructor. I want to know how it achieves this effect?

@zhengruan it just quits the application which kills the threads, you won't notice the difference unless you use a debugger or inspect the return code of main.
